# Can't debug properly in Xcode because of media playback buttons

Tags: xcode, macos

I've been working with Xcode for several months now but I can't debug my applications via shortcuts (F7 - F12) because the media playback functionality (play, pause, etc) override Xcode's purpose.  For example if I am debugging and strike F8 (Step Out) Spotify will play or pause instead of Xcode stepping out.  How do I disable this feature?

Answer (score 1):

After looking through some more documentation this can be disabled in System Preferences under the keyboard section by checking the 'Use all F keys as standard function keys'